# selecting rows that are older than current date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with fields for a start and end date/time.

How would i select just the rows that are older than the current date using php.

The format of the end-date is `2009-11-25 08:01:00` and the field type is `datetime`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided timestamps and the MySQL are in the same timezone, you can just compare to [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now).

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date_col < NOW()
```

Comment: That works provided your time zone never changes; for example daylight saving time.

But if you're sane you'll set all your servers clocks to UTC.

Answer (score 2):

It might look something like:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE datefield < NOW()');
if (! $result) { die(mysql_error()); }
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // handle contents of $row
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL query would resemble:

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table t
 WHERE t.end-date < CURDATE()
```

There's various synonyms supported to get the current date - NOW(), SYSDATE()...

Reference: [MySQL date related functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: A hyphen in the middle of a column name is surely a recipe for disaster.

Comment: I agree - I forgot to comment on it in my haste, but it is the column name supplied by the OP.